# Filling PDF in Python with special characters

Tags: python, pdf

my intention is to fill fillable pdfs that contain special characters from spanish language (such as accents and letters like "ñ").

I have tried using fillpdf library, but I am not able to read correctly those characters:

```
from fillpdf import fillpdfs

pdf_fields = fillpdfs.get_form_fields("some_file.pdf")
```

When I print pdf_fields variable, I get characters like these:

```
{'■ \x00A\x005\x00[\x000\x00]': '', '■ \x00A\x006\x00[\x000\x00]': '', '■ \x00A\x007\x00[\x000\x00]': ''}
```

And I was expecting to be something like this:

```
{'field_name1': '', 'field_name2': '', 'field_name3': ''}
```

EDIT:
[Here](https://www.gva.es/downloads/publicados/IN/27352_P.pdf) is a sample PDF that I would like to fill.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Without access to the actual file, we can only speculate; but https://tripleee.github.io/8bit/#c9 suggests that the character set is Windows code page 437 (or one of several others) when you expected 1252 (or ditto ditto). Probably review [the Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag info page](/tags/character-encoding/info) for a bit of background and pointers to troubleshooting information.

Comment: https://tripleee.github.io/8bit/#d3 narrows it down to code page 850 and a few related ones.

Comment: This library? I was unable to install it because of a dependency problem. https://pypi.org/project/fillpdf/

Comment: Yes! exactly, that library